# Enabling SSL on a subdomain with AWS S3 and ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I have a site `example.com` that lives on S3.  I have set up HTTP -> HTTPS forwarding successfully for this site.

I also have a subdomain, `blog.example.me` that also lives on S3, which I want to enable SSL with.  Right now, it only supports HTTP.  I am using Route 53 for routing and Cloudfront as a CDN.

I have looked for documentation on this issue, but have yet to find something that works.  Do I have to create a new certificate, or can I use the same cert that `example.com` uses?  If I can use the same certificate, which piece of AWS should I start with?

Comment: For the certificate it depends if its a `wildcard certificate` that covers the whole domain example of a wildcard certificate would be`*.example.com` the you can use the same certificate for your `sub domain`.

Comment: @iamcaleberic I have two certificates - one for `example.com` and another for the wildcard cert - `*.example.com`.  Do you think they are conflicting somehow?

Comment: One wildcard certificate `*.example.com` can cover the main domain and the subdomains. Though there should be no conflict because you select which certificate to use when creating your cloudfront distribution.

Comment: for your blog make sure you use the wildcard `*.example.com`, the `example.com one wont work`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the certificate it depends if its a wildcard certificate that covers the whole domain example of a wildcard certificate would be `*.example.com` the you can use the same certificate for your `sub domain(s)`

A typical hosted secured site with S3 and Cloudfront would follow the following steps

`Create an S3 Bucket`

Bucket name - your domain name

Select your bucket, go to Properties -> Static Website Hosting, then Enable 
Website Hosting

Grant public read access to allow cloudfront to read from your bucket.

`Get SSL certficate/ Use existing if applies`

AWS provides free SSL certificates, which work with browsers that support SNI. You can import your own SSL certificate.

`CloudFront configuration`

> Create a new Web distribution. Under Origin Settings, use the Endpoint
>   you copied from your S3 bucket’s static hosting setup. Many other
>   guides instruct this without explaining why — this is because if you
>   have redirect rules configured with your S3 bucket and you specify the
>   internal AWS S3 resource, the redirects will no longer work.
>   Therefore, you must specify the website endpoint domain to ensure
>   redirection functionality works.
>
> Under Default Cache Behavior Settings, it’s worth selecting Redirect
>   HTTP to HTTPS and narrowing down the Allowed HTTP Methods — for a
>   static website, GET and HEAD will do.

Under cloudfront distribution settings configure:

- Set your domain names under Alternate Domain Names (yourdomain.com,
  and optionally, www.yourdomain.com)
- Configure SSL by selecting Custom SSL Certificate, then choosing the
  certificate generated or imported in to Certificate Manager.
- Finally, specify the Default Root Object. This should match your S3
  bucket’s Index Document, usually index.html. This is simply where all
  requests are redirected to when a client requests your website URL
  without a path

`Route 53 configuration:`

- Head over to hosted zones
- Select the hosted zone for the domain or subdomain you wish to use
- Create a record for your site: select Alias and in the dropdown you should see your cloudfront distribution, select it as your alias target and save it.

**For more detailed info check: https://medium.com/@willmorgan/moving-a-static-website-to-aws-s3-cloudfront-with-https-1fdd95563106**

Comment: cloudfront is not letting me add my third party cert - option is greyed out